# Количество цифр в String

Tags: java, строки

Как узнать?

Пример:

```
String s = "asdasljdi2";
```

В стринге есть одна цифра, это цифра 2.

Как грамотно это узнать без конченных частых проверок на `if(s.contains("1") || s.contains("2"))` и т.д.?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы используете JDK 8, то есть менее понятный, но более короткий код

```
public class CharCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "this 1 text contains 2 digits";
        long count = text.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit)
            .count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Прекрасно работает! Спасибо!
P.S. Для JDK 8 самое то

Answer (score 4):

Компилятора под рукой нет, но

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

наверняка есть более красивые итерационные решения, но я в яве пока еще новичок

Comment: Ответ тоже верен, но учитывая, что работаю на jdk 8, выберу нижний вариант через фильтр. ;) Спасибо.

Comment: @finfan, а Вы померьте время (скажем, 1000000 циклов для строк из 10000 символов) для этих вариантов.

Очень часто текстуально короткий код выполняется не очень-то быстро.

Comment: @avp новые Stream в jdk 8 очень даже производительны, посмотрите какую-нибудь презентацию по ним, или почитайте документацию

Comment: @Mage, это все слова, а хотелось бы увидеть цифры.

Comment: @avp померяйте сами :). Достаточно сказать, что обработку запускает только метод count(), по той же логике, что и императивный вариант с циклом. Поэтому производительность не должна сильно страдать.

Comment: Достойный ответ.

Comment: @avp, @Mage: Разумеется, вычисление лямбды затратнее, чем прямой вызов, так что производительность будет ниже чем у «прямолинейного» варианта. Поскольку расходы на цикл малы, относительная эффективность может «поплыть» и довольно сильно.

Эффективность LINQ-оидного подхода проявляется для больших объёмов данных, когда в игру вступает locality процессорного кэша, накладные расходы на контейнеры (без которых можно обойтись в случае ленивого генератора) и нагрузка на сборщик мусора. Суть состоит не в эффективности, а в привнесении в процедурный язык логики, типичной для функциональных языков.

Comment: И все-таки я ее замерил. 

Нашел Java 8 online IDE http://www.compilejava.net/ наваял тестик http://pastebin.com/mViJdDY8 (лучшие для Java 8 миллисекунды в этом тексте) пару раз запустил...

...и получил разницу в ПЯТЬ С ЛИШНИМ РАЗ!

Comment: О, я тоже :) http://pastebin.com/mBNX5fT5 даёт на том же compilejava.net

> Direct way: 27 ms, result: 524288  
> Modern way: 42 ms, result: 524288

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего это самый ресурсозатратный и медленный способ, но занимает все одну строку.

```
int count = входная_строка.replace("[^0-9]", "").length();
```

Comment: в качестве puzzler-а - неплохо